# Recurring Job in Asp.net Core Hangfire

Tags: asp.net-core, cron, console-application, jobs, hangfire

I have to run two jobs, every day at 12 AM (UTC) in my asp.net core console application. I've used two nuget packages: "Hangfire(v1.7.22)" & "Hangfire.MemoryStorage(v1.7.0)" to do the process.The problem is one of the RecurringJob is executed and other isn't.

Here is my Program.cs code:

```
 serviceCollection.AddHangfire(options => options.UseMemoryStorage());
 serviceCollection.AddHangfireServer();
 serviceCollection.AddHostedService<DemoJob>();
```

Below is my hosted service class:

```
public class DemoJob : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ILogger<DemoJob> _logger;

    public DemoJob(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<DemoJob> logger)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<DemoJob>(
            nameof(DemoJob),
            x => x.MethodOne(),
            Cron.Daily());

        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<DemoJob>(
            nameof(DemoJob),
            x => x.MethodTwo(),
            Cron.Daily());

        await Task.Delay(-1, stoppingToken);
    }

    public async Task MethodOne()
    {
        //do something
    }

    public async Task MethodTwo()
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

The problem is every time MethodOne() is being ignored and  MethodTwo() is called. If I place  MethodTwo() before MethodOne() in ExecuteAsync() then MethodOne() is called and MethodTwo() is ignored.

Comment: Have you tried executing methods of a different class (not the backgroundservice itself)? I'd try extracting `MethodOne` & `MethodTwo` to a separate class first

Comment: Yes, I've tried this, but ended with no luck!

Comment: Maybe increasing the worker count helps?

Comment: I found the problem.  In two of the Recurring job I used the same job id as nameof(DemoJob) which causes only one job to run at a time.

Comment: Nice catch, Hangfire should have thrown an exception at app startup (but it doesn't), though.